# How can I make a python commandline program importable as a library in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python program and it's directory is in following format:

```
- program: 
  - LICENSE
  - README.md 
  - VERSION   
  - setup.cfg 
  - setup.py

  - bin:
    - program_name

  - test:
    - test_qbatch.py
```

If I install this program via `pip`, it's installable.

If I try to import this program using python

```
python
>>> import program_name
```

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named program_name
```

**How can I make this program run through commandline (which it's already) as well as by importing as a library in python?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a __init__.py in your folder for it to be considered as a Python Module.